# How can the Senate remove the majority leader?

Tags: united-states, senate, senate-rules

If the Senate majority leader is refusing to do his job, can the other Senators vote to expel him or force a vote for new leadership?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The following are all options I'm aware of:

- A [2/3 of the Senate (67+ votes) can vote to expel any sitting Senator](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/briefing/Expulsion_Censure.htm) as per Article 1, Section 5 of US Constitution. An expelled Senator can of course no longer serve as a Majority leader.

  > "Each House [of Congress] may determine the Rules of its proceedings, punish its members for disorderly behavior, and, with the concurrence of two-thirds, expel a member."

  This requires at least 17+ votes from Majority party in 50/50 Senate, and at least 20+ Majority party votes in current 53 majority Senate, assuming that 100% of minority party unanimously agrees.

  This is **the only option available** that members of the minority party can contribute to directly, obviously with participation of at least a meaningful part of majority party.

  **All other options are 100% outside the control of minority party senators.**
- A Majority Leader can be pressured to resign from the position voluntarily ([Trent Lott was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trent_Lott#Resignation_from_Senate_leadership), for example).
- A Majority party caucus votes to elect a new Majority leader every 2 years, during Congress change. Majority party can then choose to elect someone else.
- In theory, Majority party caucus can vote to elect a new Majority leader (as they are the ones who decide who leads them) **at any time**. I haven't found a single case of that happening, but also no mention of any rules preventing that.
- A combination of other effects (party switching, impeachments, resignations, deaths, next elections, etc...) can cause opposite party to take Majority.

Comment: A good reminder that there is a large section of the American constitution that is not part of The Constitution, but consists of rules, traditions, conventions... not unlike the constitution of another English speaking realm.